# mod_rpaf not recognising RPAFheader setting

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, varnish, mod-rpaf

After installing mod_rpaf, I set my config file (/etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf) as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
    RPAFheader X-Real-IP
</IfModule>
```

However, now when I restart apache2 I get an error:

> Invalid command 'RPAFheader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configuration

Removing the RPAFheader line resolves the problem, but I really need this setting. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What distro and version of Linux are you using?  The `RPAFheader` command was added in version 0.6 of mod_rpaf and older versions of some distros still use 0.5.

Comment: @Ladadadada Thanks for your reply - I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.4. Do you know what version of the distro this uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu 10.04 includes version 0.5 of mod_rpaf](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/libapache2-mod-rpaf) but the `RPAFheader` command was [added in version 0.6](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/).  Ubuntu 12.04 comes with [mod_rpaf version 0.6 for some architectures and 0.5 for others](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/libapache2-mod-rpaf).

[Ubuntu 12.04 also contains a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-rpaf/+bug/1002571) which means you have to change

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
```

into

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf-2.0.c>
```

before it will work.

---

Note that with Apache 2.4, mod_rpaf is no longer needed and is replaced by mod_remoteip.

Comment: For future reference, [these instructions](http://mclear.co.uk/2011/09/09/how-to-install-mod_rpaf-varnish-wordpress-ubuntu/) showed me how to install the current version of mod_rpaf. I was then able to use RPAFheader.